# glossaries - hyperlink to custom label

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

Is there any way of getting a glossary hyperlink to link to a custom label instead of the glossary entry?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[debug=showtargets]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{FEA}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\section{BRING ME HERE} \label{bring-me-here} 

\lipsum

\gls{FEA}

\end{document}
```

I would like the `\gls{FEA}` entry to bring me to the `bring-me-here` label.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[debug=showtargets]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{FEA}{FEA}{Finite Element Analysis}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\section{BRING ME HERE} \label{bring-me-here}

\lipsum

{\glsdisablehyper\hyperref[bring-me-here]{\gls{FEA}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically for the first abbreviation in each chapter?

Comment: it is no clear what should be the automatism. How should the term know where to point to?

Comment: Perhaps with `gls:(abbreviation)`?

Comment: There is a starred version of `\gls` that dupresses hyperlinks, so the somewhat simpler `\hyperref[bring-me-here]{\gls*{FEA}}` works, too.